# using mysql to send a database of log messages to syslog-ng?

Tags: mysql, proxy, syslog-ng

I want to create a database of my proxy-server log messages and then modify and change them then finally send them to syslog-ng!!

Is it possible?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle ,I know that,but my problem is to send database to syslog-ng!!

Comment: My question is obvious, i can send my access.log logs from squid with [log_to_db](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/log_db_daemon.8.html)  to mysql and then i want to send them to syslog-ng,but i don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about the access.log file, I think it would be easier to read this file with syslog-ng, process them as you want, and then send them to sql from syslog-ng.
I'd recommend checking the [syslog-ng docs](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/list/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/) for a start.

Comment: But i want to add some field to those logs. in this way you suggested i cant do that

Comment: Well, it depends on the fields and where you get the data to those fields. syslog-ng can be very flexible, so you might be able to do it, but it depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve.